How were those shrine niches originally called?
A recent excavation in Pompeii revealed a rather rare blue (caeruleum?) shrine. In this there are 3 niches of red color. How those are called in Latin?

(Image taken from here - pompeiisites.org)

The formal term is an aedicula, but in casual conversation the word nidus, a shelf, is used. nidus literally means a "nest", but figuratively can be any small shelf, niche or small cubby.

aedicula definitely seems like the word. Do you have a reference for that usage of nidus?

Thanks, I missed that. Now, I see also zotheca is an option (probably less common). For nidus I saw that is the source for the English niche but could not see it was used in this sense in classical Latin.
